# count with if in single table and show result in two separate column - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have table like table-name perms i need to get result like where uid =1 and pid = 1 and count with 0 value as counter1 and count with 1 value as counter2

```
uid    pid  oid  value
 1      1    15    0
 1      1    17    1
 1      1    18    0
```

i am able to get simple count like this

```
SELECT *,count(*) as counter1 from perms where uid = 1 and pid = 1 and value = 0
```

how to get counter2 in same query as separate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` condition like

```
select *,
sum(case when `value` = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as counter1,
sum(case when `value` = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as counter2
from perms 
where uid = 1 
and pid = 1;
```